# Remove duplicate values and need to assign a unique variable to removed duplicates in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data set of sequences with name and I need to remove the duplicates which I have done by using

```
my_data(my_data[!duplicated(my_data$Sequence),])
```

where `my_data` is my file name, and my data file is

```
  Name      Sequence
1 KR820422  MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTKGVGSP*
2 KR820423  MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*
3 KR820424  MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*
4 KR820425  MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*
5 KR820426  MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*
6 KR820427  MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNKSGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSS*
```

I need to assign unique variables A, B, C, D, etc. for each unique duplicate. The end goal is to assign each unique duplicated sequence assigned A, B, C, etc. back to the original sequence so that there are 3 columns of

| Name | Sequence | Variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name 1 | sequence 1 | A |
| name 2 | sequence 2 | B |
| name 3 | sequence 3 | A |

Where say sequence 1 and 3 both have duplicate sequence A.

Thanks for any time and help with this issue!! Been trying a few things and haven't been able to get it to work quite yet

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("KR820422", "KR820423", "KR820424", "KR820425", "KR820426", "KR820427"),
  Sequence = c(
    "MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTKGVGSP*",
    "MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*",
    "MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*",
    "MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*",
    "MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*",
    "MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNKSGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSS*"
  ))
```

Comment: Please spend some time editing this question - it's very difficult to see what the data looks like as it stands.

Comment: Hi Regan! Welcome to StackOverflow. `rev(rev) is really hard to read, please consider changing it

Comment: Will do! I tried to change up the data to make it a little easier to see. I realized after posting that it looked a little like a dumpster fire with my data. Hopefully the new format helps! Sorry about that!!!

Comment: did you want something like `mutate(df, id = LETTERS[consecutive_id(Sequence)])`? Bearing in mind, with this, you're going to run out of letters after the 26th unique sequence

Comment: I added a dataframe version of it. Let me know if it doesn't match

Comment: @Mark thanks for adding the dataframe I will keep that formatting in mind for future reference/posts. Thanks everyone for being so patient and nice with this!! If I do mutate I need the values to correlate to the extracted duplicate sequences. Each sequence has a duplicate I need to extract the duplicates which I did with the earlier code now I need to assign identifiers to the duplicates (A,b,C...) and identify which sequences have which duplicates, like does sequence 1 have duplicate A, B, or C

Comment: no stress! The general best practice when making an R question is 1. explain what you're trying to do, 2. what you're stuck on, 3. what you've tried, 4. give a small sample input, and 5. the desired output. If you can do those things, you'll be in the top 1% of question askers, and you'll get an answer extremely quickly

Comment: Thank you! I will make sure my next post is more organized. Sorry about that initial bump!! Still learning :)

Comment: @ReganMyers did you try the mutate code I posted?

Comment: Yes I did, does that only assign a unique ID for each sequence line or for the extracted duplicate codes? It looks like that line is for assigning these values to each sequence. I could use it if I uploaded the duplicate values in a separate line and then did the mutate code

Comment: Try `df$Variable <- LETTERS[match(df$Sequence, unique(df$Sequence))]`. Btw, the code you post `my_data(...)` makes no sense because `my_data` is not a function but a dataframe.

Comment: @ReganMyers assuming your data is sorted, they should be the same thing

Answer (score 2):

One way to generate an ID by sequence is to group by sequence and use `cur_group_id()`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Sequence) %>% 
  mutate(ID = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Result (scroll right to see all 3 columns):

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Name     Sequence                                                                                                        ID
  <chr>    <chr>                                                                                                        <int>
1 KR820422 MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTKGVGSP*     2
2 KR820423 MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*     4
3 KR820424 MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*     4
4 KR820425 MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*     4
5 KR820426 MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*     1
6 KR820427 MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNKSGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSS*     3
```

I guess you could use `LETTERS[cur_group_id()]` if you want the ID to be a letter - up to 26 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I slightly reordered your data frame, so one of the duplicates comes after a different sequence, as I think this is what you were missing from the suggestions in the comments first. Of course, the extra step of matching works just fine, but if you convert Sequence to a factor, it is actually stored as integer value, allowing you to index `LETTERS` as suggested.
If you have too many different sequences, consider just putting V1, V2, ... as done in Variable2.

For comparison, I added the `consecutive_id()` option, which is not suited to find duplicates across the data set.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("KR820422", "KR820423", "KR820424", "KR820425", "KR820426", "KR820427"),
  Sequence = c(
    "MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTKGVGSP*",
    "MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*",
    "MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*",
    "MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*",
    "MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*",
    "MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNKSGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSS*"
  )) %>% 
  slice(c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4))


df %>% 
  mutate(
    Sequence = factor(Sequence) %>% fct_inorder(),
    Variable = LETTERS[Sequence],
    Variable2 = paste0('V', as.numeric(Sequence))
  ) 
#>       Name
#> 1 KR820422
#> 2 KR820423
#> 3 KR820424
#> 4 KR820426
#> 5 KR820427
#> 6 KR820425
#>                                                                                                       Sequence
#> 1 MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTKGVGSP*
#> 2 MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*
#> 3 MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*
#> 4 MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*
#> 5 MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVPLQLPPIERLNINCNKSGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSS*
#> 6 MAGRSGDSDATLLQAVKIIKILYQSNPYPKPEGTRQARKNRRRRWRARQRQIRAISERILSDCLGRPAEPVSLQLPPIERLNINCNESGGTSGTQQPQGNTEGVGSP*
#>   Variable
#> 1        A
#> 2        B
#> 3        B
#> 4        C
#> 5        D
#> 6        B

# Note that for consecutive_id() the value changes, everytime the value changes, irrespective of whether it was seen before
# df %>% 
#  mutate(Variable = consecutive_id(Sequence))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>